# Symfony2 - Setting up a tag cloud in the side bar

Tags: symfony, tags, doctrine, posts

I'm looking to recreate the tag cloud sidebar you normally see in blogs where the user selects on a tag and it brings up all posts that has that specific tag.

Right now I am having trouble figuring how to setup the query.

I have the query to pull all the tags:

```
$blogTags = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
        ->select('b.tags')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    return $blogTags;
```

But how do I set it up to where it pulls up only the posts by that tag selected by the user from a group of tags in the sidebar?

I have the code that stores the tags and weights them in the sidebar, I'm looking for the next step to link the tags to their specific posts.

**getsTags()**

```
public function getTags()
{
    $blogTags = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
        ->select('b.tags')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    $tags = array();

    foreach ($blogTags as $blogTag) {
        $tags = array_merge(explode(",", $blogTag['tags']), $tags);
    }

    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $tag = trim($tag);
    }

    return $tags;
}
```

**getTagWeights()**

```
public function getTagWeights($tags)
{
    $tagWeights = array();
    if (empty($tags))
        return $tagWeights;

    foreach ($tags as $tag)
    {
        $tagWeights[$tag] = (isset($tagWeights[$tag])) ? $tagWeights[$tag] + 1 : 1;
    }
    // Shuffle the tags
    uksort($tagWeights, function() {
        return rand() > rand();
    });

    $max = max($tagWeights);

    // Max of 5 weights
    $multiplier = ($max > 5) ? 5 / $max : 1;
    foreach ($tagWeights as &$tag)
    {
        $tag = ceil($tag * $multiplier);
    }

    return $tagWeights;
}
```

Comment: store a counter in the tags table, after that you can show the tags by its popularity using the counter

Comment: Right I have that, but I'm looking for the next step where I select on a tag and it brings up the corresponding posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps others from spending hrs and hrs on this.

```
public function getPostsByTags($tag)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
        ->where('b.tags like :tag')
        ->setParameter('tag', '%'.$tag.'%');

    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as your friend ([Symfony2 - Need help setting up a doctrine query for finding tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178723/symfony2-need-help-setting-up-a-doctrine-query-for-finding-tags/23179649#23179649))

You should use a doctrine query.

**PostRepository.php**

```
public function findByTagName($tagName)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('post');
    $qb->select('post')
        ->join('post.tags', 'tag')
        ->where('tag.name LIKE ?', '%'.$tagName.'%');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```