# Symfony2 - Need help setting up a doctrine query for finding tags

Tags: symfony, tags, doctrine, tag-cloud

I've been looking far and wide and still haven't been able to find an example of how to setup a query to look for a specific 'tag' that the user selects from a sidebar which in turn will bring up all posts with that tag.

I understand how to find all tags, but not to find a specific selected by the user.

**blogrepository**

```
public function getTags($tags)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('b');
    $qb->select('b')
        ->join('b.tags', 'tag')
        ->where('b.tags LIKE ?', '%'.$tags.'%');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

**blog entity**

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="tags", type="text")
 */
private $tags;

/**
 * Set tags
 *
 * @param string $tags
 * @return Blog
 */
public function setTags($tags)
{
    $this->tags = $tags;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get tags
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTags()
{
    return $this->tags;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will work for you.

```
public function getPostsByTags($tag)
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
            ->where('b.tags like :tag')
            ->setParameter('tag', '%'.$tag.'%');

        return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1st solution : You should use a doctrine query.

**PostRepository.php**

```
public function findByTagName($tagName)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('post');
    $qb->select('post')
        ->join('post.tags', 'tag')
        ->where('tag.name LIKE ?', '%'.$tagName.'%');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

2nd solution : Use Many To Many relation and get directly from doctrine

**Entity/Tag.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="YourApp\YourBundle\Entity\Post", inversedBy="tags")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="posts_tags")
 */
private $posts;
```

**Entity/Post.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="YourApp\YourBundle\Entity\Tag", mappedBy="posts")
 */
private $tags;
```

So you can do `$tag->getPosts();` to get all relative posts

3rd solution : Really ugly, but the tutorial is not designed to be improved ...
Get all blog post and parsing each string to find if your tag is in.

```
public function getBlogWithTag($tagRequested)
{
    $blogs = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
                 ->getQuery()
                 ->getResult();

    $blogsWithTag = array();
    $tags = array();
    foreach ($blogs as $blog)
    {
        $tags = explode(",", $blog->getTags());
        foreach ($tags as &$tag)
        {
            $tag = trim($tag);
        }

        if(in_array($tagRequested, $tags)) {
            array_push($blogsWithTag, $blog);
        }
    }

    return $blogsWithTag;
}
```

Comment: I get the following error: `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 78 near 'tag WHERE blog.tags': Error: Class Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Blog has no association named tags`

Comment: Used the following: `public function getPostsByTags($tags)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('b');
        $qb->select('b')
            ->join('b.tags', 'tag')
            ->where('b.tags LIKE ?', '%'.$tags.'%');

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

    }`

Comment: Updated the original post with the query I'm using that's yielding the error.

Comment: I need to see your Post and Tag entities

Comment: Updated answer with an alternative method

Comment: Added the blog entity with the tag setup. Using the example from symblog on setting up the tag cloud: http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/customising-the-view-more-with-twig.html

Comment: Is there a way to get it working with the current setup? I'd like to learn how to get it work this way before changing it up.

Comment: Update answer keeping current config (but you should try to improve the code, because this tutuarial is not designed to be improved)