# Symfony2 - Need help on the following error when querying for tags

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, tags, tag-cloud

Having the following error in my doctrine query when trying to find a specific tag selected by the user.

***[Semantical Error] line 0, col 78 near 'tag WHERE blog.tags': Error: Class Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Blog has no association named tags***

Can someone tell what's wrong with the query? (trying to query for a tag selected in the side bar that brings up all posts related to the tag)

**Repository**

```
public function getPostsByTags($tags)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('b');
    $qb->select('b')
        ->join('b.tags', 'tag')
        ->where('b.tags LIKE ?', '%'.$tags.'%');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

}
```

**Blog Entity**

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="tags", type="text")
 */
private $tags;

/**
 * Set tags
 *
 * @param string $tags
 * @return Blog
 */
public function setTags($tags)
{
    $this->tags = $tags;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get tags
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTags()
{
    return $this->tags;
}
```

**Controller**

```
/**
 * @Route("/tag/{tag}", name="AcmeDemoBundle_tag")
 * @Template("AcmeDemoBundle:Page:tag.html.twig")
 */
public function tagAction($tag = null)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $tags = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Blog')
        ->getPostsByTags($tag);

    if (!$tags) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find blog posts');
    }

    return array(
        'tags'  => $tags,
    );
}
```

**Sidebar Twig**

```
<p class="tags">
    {% for tag, weight in tags %}
    <span class="weight-{{ weight }}"><a href="{{ path('AcmeDemoBundle_tag', { 'tag': tag }) }}">{{ tag }}</a></span>
    {% else %}
<p>There are no tags</p>
{% endfor %}
</p>
```

**Tag results twig**

```
{% block body %}
{% for tag in tags %}
    <article class="result">
        <div class="date"><time datetime="{{ tag.created|date('c') }}">{{ tag.created|date('l, F j, Y') }}</time></div>
        <header>
            <h2><a href="{{ path('AcmeDemoBundle_show', { 'id': tag.id, 'slug': tag.slug }) }}">{{ tag.title }}</a></h2>
        </header>

        <img src="{{ asset(['images/', tag.image]|join) }}" />
        <div class="snippet">
            <p>{{ tag.blog|truncate(250, true) }}</p>
            <p class="continue"><a href="{{ path('AcmeDemoBundle_show', { 'id': tag.id, 'slug': tag.slug }) }}">More...</a></p>
        </div>

        <footer class="meta">
            <p>Comments: -</p>
            <p>Posted by <span class="highlight">{{tag.author}}</span> at {{ tag.created|date('h:iA') }}</p>
            <p>Tags: <span class="highlight">{{ tag.tags }}</span></p>
        </footer>
    </article>
{% else %}
    <p>There are no blog entries for Health&Fitness blog</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**Updated solution: repository query** (no blogs found)

```
public function getPostsByTags($tags)
{

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
        ->where('b.tags = :tags')
        ->setParameter('tags', $tags);

    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

**Updated solution: controller using query** (no blogs found)

```
public function tagAction(tags=null)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $repository = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Blog');

    $tags = $repository->createQueryBuilder('b')
        ->where('b.tags = :tags')
        ->setParameter('tags', $tags)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    return array(
        'tags' => $tags,
    );
}
```

Comment: In blog entity there is no relation defined for tags and in query  you are using unmapped join

Comment: So what do I need to do to correct this?

Comment: You need to read the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#relationship-mapping-metadata)  carefully to map your entities based on their nature of relation one to many or many to many

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `getPostsByTags` function to:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Blog');

$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('b')
->where('b.tags = :tags')
->setParameter('tags', $tags)
->getQuery();

return $query->getResult();
```

Comment: Trying this I get: Undefined method 'getDoctrine'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!

Comment: Updated original query with what I used. But am getting a No blogs found with the query.

Comment: Try replacing `LIKE` with `=`, like the updated answer.

Comment: Using = doesn't work, "No blogs found". Updated original question with '=' instead of 'like'.

Comment: Updated question showing the 2 methods I've used with your suggested query (repository and controller) they both do not bring back any results.

Comment: It must be something related to your `$tags` variable and `tags` property. You can echo `$tags` and compare with your Database values to see the differences.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by echo $tags and compare with my database values to see the difference?

Answer (score 1):

This is the query that worked. Hope this helps others.

```
public function getPostsByTags($tag)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
        ->where('b.tags like :tag')
        ->setParameter('tag', '%'.$tag.'%');

    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Comment: My answer is correct, but your variable is called `$tag` instead of `$tags`

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the answer i give to a similar problem (3rd solution) : [Symfony2 - Need help setting up a doctrine query for finding tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178723/symfony2-need-help-setting-up-a-doctrine-query-for-finding-tags/23179649#23179649)

```
public function getBlogsWithTag($tagRequested)
{
$blogs = $this->findAll();

$blogsWithTag = array();
$tags = array();
foreach ($blogs as $blog)
{
    $tags = explode(",", $blog->getTags());
    foreach ($tags as &$tag)
    {
        $tag = trim($tag);
    }

    if(in_array($tagRequested, $tags)) {
        array_push($blogsWithTag, $blog);
    }
}

return $blogsWithTag;
}
```

Comment: You have a single blog post ?

Comment: Sure, but it's not our aim. We would find all blog to process each of them. Id findAll return nothing. Something elsewhere is broken.

Comment: You have all blogs, you have the alorithm, you need to debug it now. I can't do so more in your place.